# Can I use swagger test template with non nodejs app?

Tags: php, swagger, web-api-testing

I'm working in building out a api test suite for a php application. Right now the app is using swagger annotation and I can easily create a swagger.json. But from looking at [the swagger test template](http://apigee.com/about/blog/developer/swagger-test-templates-test-your-apis), it looks like I have to create a nodejs app first using swagger node? Is there a way I can skip that step and use my php app instead?

Edit: I already have the swagger docs up and running using swagger-php. Just wondering if it's possible to use swagger-test-template without using swagger-node.

Answer (score 4):

I am one of the contributors on swagger-test-templates. (I haven't answered anything on SO before so bear with me)

I was brought to your question through a Github issue someone recently opened to address this! I answered it there, but I will copy it here and expand on it some more. I hope it helps. Please follow up if I didn't completely answer your question.

> Simple answer: No, it is not exclusively for Node.js APIs or swagger-node.
>
> Longer answer: You can use STT like any other Node.js module in a Node.js project, completely on its own. See the [Readme](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-test-templates/blob/master/README.md) or the test files for an example of how to run it standalone. Furthermore, the API doesn't have to be implemented in Node.js for a STT generated test to target it with an HTTP request. You have to use Node.js to utilize this module's functionality, but as long as you point the tests at a running server (localhost:1337, my.api.test.net) the backend implementation doesn't matter. The caveat here is that this module was designed to run with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) which is a Node.js test runner/framework. So the tests have to be in a Node.js project, but the server implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP API client generated by Swagger Codegen comes with test cases (template) that need to be updated with test data. You can find some examples in this [folder](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/php/SwaggerClient-php/tests)

To run the test cases, just follow the instruction in the [README.md](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/php/SwaggerClient-php/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question today, and found this thread which had no resolution.

So I [asked the project developers](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-test-templates/issues/133) and they said it can do what you want.

> Simple answer: No, it is not exclusively for Node.js APIs.
>
> Longer answer: The API doesn't have to be implemented in Node.js for a
>   STT generated test to target it with an HTTP request. You have to use
>   Node.js to utilize this module (obviously), but as long as you point
>   the tests at a running server (localhost:1337, my.api.test.net) the
>   implementation doesn't matter. The caveat here is that this module was
>   designed to run with mocha which is a Node.js test runner/framework.
>   So the tests have to be in a Node.js project, but the server
>   implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate server application for different platforms not only nodejs, using their tool 'swagger-codegen' or in [online editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/): paste you swagger configuration and choose generate server -> Silex PHP.

Comment: I already have the php code up and running, using swagger-php. Is it possible to set up swagger-test-tempate or something similar without doing this all in swagger-node?

Comment: @JLau `swagger-test-template` is nodejs only, here's the list of non-commercial tools available for swagger by language http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/ what I see test related there's https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions

Comment: Ah thanks. I was hoping I can use js since I already use [chakram](http://dareid.github.io/chakram/) to run my api tests.

Answer (score -1):

Definately you can do so. Go to `https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui` , download the zip. Zip file has a `dist` folder. That is all you need for developing the swagger docs in your API server. Include this folder in your server directory along with the Php code. Inside `dist` there is index.html and swagger.json. You can modify these two files to create your own docs and test your API.

Comment: I already have swagger docs up and running using swagger-php. I'm trying to find a way to use swagger-test-template from my current php app.