# Generate Unit Test Code from Swagger API for Java REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, swagger, swagger-2.0

I was trying using Swagger test templates and found this an interesting tool to generate the test files for my controllers, but It seems to just work for NodeJs projects, because there is not a similar tool for the Java platform.

Do somebody knows about how to generate these Test files from my controllers by using a swagger file for spring boot projects?

PD:

I have tried with commercial tools like RepreZen and SwaggerHub but they don't generate the test files for me.

I have also tried by using swagger-generator jar tool to generate those kind of files, but this tool just generate code for Client but no for the Server.

Thx you a lot!.

Comment: Hello did you find something suitable for your case? Something like `swagger-test-templates`, but for java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erikson,

While RepreZen API Studio doesn't currently include a generator template for unit tests, you can write a custom code generator for this purpose, using the built-in tooling and code gen framework.

More info here: http://docs.reprezen.com/#code-gen

If you'd like to collaborate on this, please feel free to get in touch with us.

Ted Epstein, CEO | RepreZen

Answer (score 7):

For testing API of Spring-family projects you can use Springfox + AssertJ Swagger libraries. Also you need a YAML file with your API specification. The main idea of this solution is to compare a contract-first Swagger YAML file with a code-first Swagger JSON generated by SpringFox.

> [Springfox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/) integrates with Spring MVC with support for Swagger 1.2 and Swagger 2.0 spec.
> Springfox is able to automatically generate JSON API documentation at runtime for API's built with Spring.

> [Assertj-Swagger](https://github.com/RobWin/assertj-swagger) is a library which compares a design-first Swagger YAML with an implementation-first Swagger JSON output (e.g. from springfox). assertj-swagger allows to validate that the implementation in compliance with the design specification.

#### Project setup example

pom.xml

```xml
<!-- http://springfox.io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.robwin</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Test code:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AssertJSwaggerConsumerDrivenTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int randomPort;

    @Test
    public void validateThatImplementationSatisfiesConsumerSpecification() {
        File designFirstSwagger = new File(AssertJSwaggerConsumerDrivenTest.class.getResource("/swagger.yaml").getFile());
        SwaggerAssertions.assertThat("http://localhost:" + randomPort + "/v2/api-docs")
                .satisfiesContract(designFirstSwagger.getAbsolutePath());
    }    
}
```

#### Troubleshooting

- Exception `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/github/robwin/swagger/test/SwaggerAssertions : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`
  Solution: Use JRE 1.8+
- Exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.models.parameters.AbstractSerializableParameter.setMaximum(Ljava/lang/Double;)V`
  At the moment of writing AssertJ-Swagger library [is incompatible](https://github.com/RobWin/assertj-swagger/issues/19) with the latest SpringFox release, so I recommend to use SpringFox v2.6.1.
- **Warning!** I find Consumer Driven Contract test too strict for my project, it gives a lot of false errors, e.g. if an actual DTO name differs from a name in the specification.
  I don't know how to fight this issue. All suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Hello. What about generating your api with swagger-codegen?

Comment: @AlexPo swagger-codegen needs templates. I haven't found any good templates for java unit tests when I researched this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Erikson,

Hi! I'm one of the contributors on swagger-test-templates. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657134/can-i-use-swagger-test-template-with-non-nodejs-app) as well, and I [answered it there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43524538/3957976), but I will copy here.

> Simple answer: No, it is not exclusively for Node.js APIs or swagger-node.
>
> Longer answer: You can use STT like any other Node.js module in a Node.js project, completely on its own. See the [Readme](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-test-templates/blob/master/README.md) or the test files for an example of how to run it standalone. Furthermore, the API doesn't have to be implemented in Node.js for a STT generated test to target it with an HTTP request. You have to use Node.js to utilize this module's functionality, but as long as you point the tests at a running server (localhost:1337, my.api.test.net) the backend implementation doesn't matter. The caveat here is that this module was designed to run with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) which is a Node.js test runner/framework. So the tests have to be in a Node.js project, but the server implementation doesn't.

EDIT:
That^ being said, it does generate Node.js code, not Java code, if that is what you were looking for. Please follow up if I can be answer anything more.